# NSXMLParser samples and ARC

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

I have seen many samples of NSXMLParser and understand how it works. For example, this one is very good:

http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser

All samples I saw use Release to release temporary objects at some point during parsing which is OK. But if I switch on ARC, I don't have access to release at all. How does the sample code change then?

For example, please look at the above code (link) and explain how would you change it with ARC ON?

Thanks.

Comment: Start by reading the Apple Advanced Memory Management Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a discussion of how one goes about making non-ARC code enabled with ARC, I'd refer you to the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html). As Midhun alludes, you will be replacing `retain` references with `strong` references and eliminating `release` and `autorelease`. You'll also be removing calls to `[super dealloc]`. So the conversion isn't hard, but there are a number of items to be conscious of.

Having said that, I disagree with your assessment that this example code is "pretty good." With no insult to the original author, it's a little outdated, and as such, is applying historical conventions rather than the modern contemporary practice (e.g. explicitly declared ivars for properties, not using underscore for ivar names, etc.). I also noticed a few bugs in the code (minor things like a missing property, more significant things like a bug in the `foundCharacters` routine, etc.).

I've cleaned up the code (both converting it to ARC and addressing a number of these issues) and have uploaded it to a [repository](https://github.com/robertmryan/nsxmlparser-demonstration) on GitHub. Note, I've done two things:

1. I've modified the code to be a little more contemporary in its practices (this is the `UsersParser` class) and fixing a few of these little bugs;
2. I've also made a rendition of this code which is a little more flexible, the `XmlArrayParser`, where the parser class isn't hard-coded for the Users XML file that the example uses. The method that calls this has to understand what elements we're looking for, but the parser itself doesn't care.

I hope this help.

Comment: A few questions:
1) I'm adding a comment for the first time. Hitting Enter commits it which is very irritating. I'm using Firefox. I tried other keys too like Alt or Ctrl with Enter. This didn't happen when submitting the question itself. Any ideas? I had to copy the comment to Notepad, edit it and paste back.

I have to enter more text for this comment but have to split it now.

Comment: 2) The main confusion that I had with ARC was that if I was using a member variable again and again, whether it is required to "nil" it to release memory or it does it automatically when you assign another value to it. From your code, I learned that I must explicitly nil it. Do I understand it correctly?

3) I have heard about GitHub but saw its use for the first time. Impressed! But I see that you have your email address easily accessible and it doesn't require a login to see it. Doesn't it cause spam?

Comment: @user173399 To your first point, that's just how comments work. (Sigh.)

Comment: @user173399 2) your original understanding of ARC variables was correct, that both setting a pointer to a new object and setting it to `nil` will release the prior object. It's just good practice to `nil`  when you no longer need it. More importantly, `foundCharacters` had bug where characters after the closing tag would get appended to the results (which is wrong). Thus I use whether `elementValue` is `nil` or not to know whether I should be appending characters. This means that when I'm done appending, I should set it to `nil`.

Comment: @user173399 3) on github, you don't need to reveal your email if you don't want. I just have an incredibly effective spam system, so I don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert it to ARC there will not be any

- retain
- release
- autorelease

keywords.

For better understanding you should convert that sample code using Xcode ARC conversion Tool.
You'll get a better understanding when you complete that.
Please refer this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1) for assistance.